# How to use std::list in an inheritance?

Tags: c++

In ShapeList.cpp, I want to push back a new data, but I do not know how to use `protected std::list<Shape*>`.
Could yo teach me how to push_back the data in add method?
main.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Square.h"
#include "ShapeList.h"
#include <fstream>
    using std::ifstream;
#include <iostream>
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cin;
    using std::string;

int main(){
    // test1
    Circle c1{0, 0, 1};
    Square s1{1, 0.5, 2.3};
    cout << "c1: " << c1 << endl;
    cout << "s1: " << s1 << endl;

    // test2
    cout << "Press <enter> to continue...";
    cin.get( );  // waits on another <enter> key
    ShapeList shapes;
    shapes.add( new Circle{1, 2.3, 3} );
    shapes.add( new Square{5, 5, 10.2} );
    cout << "List via stream insertion operator:\n";
    cout << shapes << endl;
    cout << "\nList via write method:\n";
    shapes.write( cout );
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Shape.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
public:
    Shape( double x, double y );
    void write(std::ostream& strm) const;

private:
    double ref_x;
    double ref_y;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Shape& s);

#endif
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include <iostream>
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

Shape::Shape( double x, double y ) : ref_x{x}, ref_y{y} {
    cout << "DEBUG: Executing Shape constructor...\n";
}

void Shape::write(std::ostream& strm) const{
    strm << "( "<< ref_x << ", " << ref_y << " )" << endl;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Shape& s){
    s.write(strm);
    return strm;
}
```

ShapeList.h

```
#ifndef SHAPELIST_H
#define SHAPELIST_H
#include "Shape.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class ShapeList : protected std::list<Shape*> {
public:
    ShapeList( ) = default;
    void add( Shape* newShape );
    void write( std::ostream& strm_out ) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& strm_out, const ShapeList& shapes );
};

#endif
```

ShapeList.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include "ShapeList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void ShapeList::add( Shape* newShape ){
    std::list::push_back(newShape);
}

void ShapeList::write( std::ostream& strm_out ) const{
    for ( const auto& item : *this ) {
        item->write( strm_out );
        strm_out << '\n';
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& strm_out, const ShapeList& shapes ){
    shapes.write(strm_out);
    return strm_out;
}
```

Comment: `this->push_back(newShape);`. Otherwise please create a [mcve] - minimal only and must include the desired and actual behaviour.

Comment: Please do not do this. If a C++ book told you to do this, burn it. If a teacher told you to do this, get a better teacher. `std::list` is a concrete implementation of a list, not an interface meant to be extended.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that your base type is `list<Shape*>` and not `list`. (which your compiler probably told you.)

---

That being said, though it is not really the question, inheriting form std containers is generally a bit scary. https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types/. I found it a good read about inheriting from std types.

Also, a `using` statement before an `#include` is really scary.